# Do we have anything like contains in Unified search?

Tags: elasticsearch, episerver, episerver-find

I have this line of code

```
query = query.Filter(i => 
        (
            !i.MatchTypeHierarchy(typeof(InfoPage)) 
            | (((InfoPage)i).SearchSubsection().Exists() 
            & ((InfoPage)i).GetSearchSubSection().Contains(SOMETHING))
        )
    ); // I want to check if it contains
```

I want to check if there is anything like a string contains a substring in FIND query.

Thanks for help in advance. :)

Answer (score 2):

First things first, you are casting to `InfoPage` which indicates that you shouldn't be using Unified search, instead use the typed search feature.

Second, *contains* would typically be referred to as **wildcard** search.

I wrote a typed search wildcard method a while ago, see https://www.herlitz.io/2016/09/19/episerver-find-wildcard-searching/

```
public static class SearchExtensions
{
    public static IQueriedSearch<T> WildCardSearch<T>(this ITypeSearch<T> search, string query)
    {
        return search.For<T>(query, q => q.Query = string.Concat("*", query, "*"));
    }
}
```

Usage example

```
var result = SearchClient.Instance.Search<InfoPage>()
                    .WildCardSearch(query)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Name)
                    .FilterForVisitor()
                    .GetContentResult();
```